# CSS switcher with PHP and Cookie?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, cookies

How I can create a live style and script switcher like in this page? `http://www.momizat.com/theme/goodnews/`?

they provide a panel so that visitors can easily change the appearance of the page (css) and also the effect on the menu bar (jquery). Coupled also with a cookie so that when a visitor moves to another page, the customization will remain loaded on the destination page.

I want to apply these function to my site, so my visitor will not bored with just one style, but can vary according to their tastes.

Every answer will be very appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: Writing code would be a good start: provide list of available styles, prompt for choice, set choice into cookie.

Comment: We are not here to teach you programming. YOU have to write the code, we'll try to help fix it.

Comment: Insulting the people you're asking for help is not a good idea. We're here to HELP, not do your job for you. YOU need to learn how to do this.

Comment: Have to agree with Marc B on this one - notice he has 187k rep and you have 43 rep - he is trying to help you get the most out of this site - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ <- this may be a better forum for this kind of question as it is more about the theory /  conceptual advice. The other thing I would suggest is to have a look through the javascript (as it is javascript that powers most of it) and see what is going on when you click a button.

Comment: Don't worry about it - technically you aren't in the wrong place (despite what people say there is no rule on SO that you have to show code) - but it is the general ettiquette to show your code just so we know you aren't just asking us to do it for you. Not many people are aware of programmers exchange so don't worry - I only found it this year!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't looked at the implementation of your example page, but most sites would use this approach:

- When a user clicks on the theme switcher button,

  - set the new value in the cookie
  - add a specific class name on the `body` tag (i.e. class="theme1")
- For every theme, have your CSS start with that class name (i.e. `body.theme1 p { color: red; }`)
- When the user loads the page, read the cookie and set the class name accordingly.

Comment: Or you put the theme in another style sheet and deliver that instead of your default.css

Comment: @colburton - True... I guess it depends on how different the themes are. If they just switch out the colors of the background and text, it might be better to do it class based.  If they are substantially different your approach might be much better.

Comment: Was not intended to be any critic on your answer. Just another option for the OP to choose, but not in itself worth another answer ;-)

Comment: @colburton - I didn't take it as criticism. I very much appreciated your alternative approach.  Just wanted to spell out when each would be useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you want to do this with PHP:

0) First, a session must be started on every page or this won't work because a session must be started to either initiate the cookie or access it on next page.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

1) You have to write a PHP script that starts in the HEAD tag:

```
 <?php
 if (isset($_REQUEST['theme']) ) { $_REQUEST['theme'] = $css1; echo "<link rel='text/stylesheet' href='path/to/{$css1}.css'>"; 
    else echo "<link rel='text/stylesheet' href='path/to/default.css'>"; 
 ?>
```

Okay so now if there is a cookie with a parameter called 'theme' set, the value of that parameter will be served as a css file instead of default.css.

2) Now, you need to give the user an option to switch themes, probably via a drop-down form.

```
<?php 
echo "<form name='myForm'><select onchange='this.form.submit()' name='theme'>";
echo "<option value='theme1'>Theme 1</option>";
echo "<option value='theme2'>Theme 2</option>";
echo "</select></form>";
?>
```

Note: I didn't actually run this code, I am sure there are errors but that's just a general overview of how I would do it.

To troubleshoot: make sure the form is being submitted. You can use `print_r($_REQUEST);` to dump out the contents of the cookie for troubleshooting. Then make sure the path to the CSS file is correct. Finally, once you've got it all working, make sure you're not getting a false result from the CSS file being cached. For instance, in Chrome you can open "Inspect Element" developer tool which will fully refresh the page every time.